# Why is this negative lookbehind being considered a successful regex match?

Tags: regex, perl, negative-lookbehind

I would expect that this simple text string would not be considered a match:

```
xyz@xyz:~$ echo xy | perl -n -e 'print if /y(?<!x)/'
xy
```

But strangely enough it is. I've tried it also @ https://regex101.com/ and the result is the same. It seems like it will match the `y`, which confuses me. If my understanding is correct, the above regex should only match `y`s that are *not* preceded by a `x`.

PS: I gave this a simplistic example. In general I would like to use negative lookbehinds to match against full strings and not necessarily single characters such as x.

I'm using the Perl regex flavour.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the position of the negative lookback assertion backwards.

It is zero width, so needs to be in front of the `y` as you have written it.

Given:

```
$ echo $'xy\nay\nyx' 
xy
ay
yx
```

The lookbehind `/y(?<!x)/` matches lines with `x` in front or in back of `y` because `y` is behind the assertion (not `x`):

```
$ echo $'xy\nay\nyx' | perl -n -e 'print if /y(?<!x)/'
xy
ay
yx
```

Note that `yx` also matches since the assertion comes prior to `x` and is looking at `y` so all three lines are matches.

*Vs* what you are looking for:

```
$ echo $'xy\nay\nyx' | perl -n -e 'print if /(?<!x)y/'
ay
yx
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R9qXVP/1/)

[Further explanation.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Or, you need to account for width of the `y` (or whatever the match is) if looking backwards after the `y` by including the `y` in the assertion:

```
$ echo $'xy\nay\nyx' | perl -n -e 'print if /y(?<!xy)/'
ay
yx
```

Answer (score 5):

`ab` means `a` followed by `b`. As such, you are checking for a `y` at one position, and then you check that the next position isn't preceded by `x`.
It isn't preceded by `x` —it's preceded by `y`— so the pattern matches.

You want

```
/(?<!x)y/
```

or

```
/(?:^|[^x])y/
```